# Browser Module conflicts in library/app Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular cli project that imports a UIcomponents library that I made through a relative reference in npm (npm packagr + npm pack). It works because the app is monolithic and everything is there.

My issue is: running the library standalone for development I need BrowserModule and BrowserAnimationModule. These are just required for running the lib with also using Angular animations.

The catch is that you cant import the browser module more than once so when I include the library in my Angular app now both the app and library import BrowserModule. The solution to this isolated issue is to have anything that isnt appmodule import CommonModule instead but then I have to change it back to run standalone library.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have also experienced the same issue , Please share if you have found some solution to this , It would be helpful